# Por qué no carga el Css?

Tags: html, css

[image: HTML]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUgh0.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/z14Su.jpg Calculadora de HTML
No cargan los estilos en la calculadora.
[image: Css]

Los estilos en css no aparecen en el HTML . La página sale en blanco

Comment: El código siempre _como texto, con formato_. [No todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Además, como tu código es HTML + CSS, puedes mostrar un [repro] a través de un _snippet_ (con el botón que indica `<>`) Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: En la imagen, el style.css que estás editando está fuera de la carpeta css. Muévelo a la carpeta o cambia la referencia del archivo para indicar que está en la raiz del proyecto

Comment: cual es el codigo entre las etiquetas header del html?

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente sea lo que dice @Jakala, pero si este problema persiste si ya solucionaste ese error bien puedes:

1. Usar la etiqueta  como método de emergencia.
2. Si tu carpeta se encuentra en htdocs, trata de que este lo mas cercano a esa carpeta y evita hacer subcarpetas EN LO POSIBLE.

Digo esto porque muchas veces me pasa en mi notebook. Espero que te haya sido util, saludos!